# rabl N+1 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I've got the following call in Rails 4

`@obj = A.includes(B: { C: D}).find_by_uuid(params[:id])`

Which works fine when viewing the SQL. The problem is the following RABL template creates multiple D database queries again. I'm using 0.14.0. This is the structure of my simplified Rabl.

show.rabl

```
object @obj
extends "documents/base"
```

base.rabl

```
child :B => :asb do |ab|
    object ab
    extends "shared/asb"
end
```

asb.rabl

```
child(:C => :csb) do
    attributes :id 
    child(:D => :dsb) do
         attributes :x, :y <<----------- multiple database calls
    end
  end
```